# rsync on Ubuntu - root permissions on remote machine?

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

I am trying to get some files from a mounted read-only disk on a remote computer (Ubuntu) using recursive rsync. I am the administrator on both the remote and local machine. For a few files, I am told that I don't have sufficient privileges to access their directories. I tried to rsync as root@hostname, but it rejects the password I normally use as sudo (this method works ok on an OS X machine I use). In my sshd_config file, PermitRootLogin is set to yes (and it's not an issue of sshd restart), and there list no list of DenyUsers. Is there still a way I can try to get these files? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable the root account on the other machine. `ssh` as your normal user and run

`sudo passwd root`

And type in your password. Ubuntu, by default, uses the `sudo` system, which doesn't use the `root` account but instead raises the current user's privileges.

Comment: As a note: You may want to experiment using `su` instead of `sudo` and using your `root` login like that. I prefer that (mainly because Ubuntu uses `sudo` for something `sudo` was _not_ meant to be used for)

Comment: Ah, so that's it. Regarding su/sudo - Ubuntu Community doc says: "sudo is commonly used to execute only a single command, while su is generally used to open a shell and execute multiple commands", so sudo seems fine here...

Comment: Yes, you can use it for that purpose.